# Solve linear system with absolute value constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

I have a linear system of equations
$$A(\xi)x(\xi)=b(\xi),$$
where $\xi \in \mathbb{R}_+^1$ is a parameter, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and is non-singular, and $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

I would like to **remove the parametric dependence on $\xi$** by augmenting the system of equations with an **additional constraint**. The augmented arrays (denoted by tilde) form the new augmented system of equations
$$\tilde{A}\tilde{x} = \tilde{b},$$
$$
\tilde{x} = \left[\begin{array}{c} \overline{x} \\ \xi \end{array}\right],
$$
$$
\tilde{b} = \left[\begin{array}{c} \overline{b} \\ 1 \end{array}\right] ,
$$
where the overbar terms are constant. The **specific constraint** I want to satisfy is the 1-norm of $\tilde{x}$,
$$
\xi: f(\tilde{x}) = \left( \dfrac{1}{N+1}\sum_i^{N+1} \left| \tilde{x}^i \right| \right) - 1 = 0,
$$
which makes defining $\tilde{A}$ problematic: I know the **magnitude** of all elements in $\tilde{A}$ with certainty, but the **absolute value** on $\left| \tilde{x}^i \right|$ prevents me from turning this into a linear system of equations since the **signs** of $\tilde{x}$ are unknown. **If the signs of $\tilde{x}$ can be known with certainty**, then I will be able to solve $\tilde{x} = \tilde{A}^{-1}\tilde{b}$.

Is there any way to solve for $\tilde{x}$ with linear algebra?

### What I've tried so far

A working (but inelegant) solution is to perform Newton's method in order to satisfy the constraint on $\xi$. The basic premise is that I can perform a finite difference approximation to compute
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} = \dfrac{ f \left(  x(\xi + \Delta \xi) \right) - f \left(  x(\xi) \right) }{\Delta \xi},
$$
where
$$
x(\xi) = A^{-1}(\xi)b(\xi)
$$
and $\Delta$ is some small positive perturbation. Then, I perform Newton's method to iteratively reduce the magnitude of $f(x)$. I know this works because I've coded and verified it, so I'm hoping there is a solution to the core problem.